# Heap out of memory exception

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

In my eclipse, while running a mapreduce program, it is throwing **Out of memory exception**
I tryied with changing the parameters in eclipse.ini (-Xms40m
-Xmx768m values to -Xms4000m
-Xmx7680m) but still getting the same error.
What would be the solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `eclipse.ini` setting only sets the heap for Eclipse itself.

For a program you run from Eclipse look at the `Run Configuration` for the program and set the -Xmx value in the `VM arguments`.